# SQL - How to "filter out" people who has more than 1 status

Tags: sql, impala

I tried to find this question here but I probably didn't know the exact term to search for.

Here is the problem:

I have this set of customers (see image). I need to filter only those with status "user_paused" or "interval_paused". A same customer_id may have more than 1 status, and sometimes, this status can be "active". If so, this customer should not appear in my final result.

See customer 809 - he shouldn't appear in my final result since he has an "active" status. all the others are fine, because they only have paused statuses.

I still couldn't figure out how to proceed from here.

Thank you so much.

[image: IMAGE HERE!]

Comment: will paused_statuses<>statuses and status<>'active' work?

Comment: You need to select them distinct rather than one time per status?

Comment: Oh, I think I didn't make myself clear. I can't filter out using status <> active because I need to remove both entries for that specific customer. So, as the image shows, customer 809 has both status, interval_paused and active. I need to remove both entries. If I use status <> active, it would still return one entry.

Comment: Show an exemple of the desidered result

Comment: The desired result would be exactly the same, but without the customer 809 (both entries would be removed, since for me, no matter how many paused entries he has, if at least 1 is active, he is considered active).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `group by` and `having`:

```
select customer_id
from t
group by customer_id
having sum(case when status not in ('user_paused', 'interval_paused') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  customer_id FROM TABLE
WHERE status IN ( 'user_paused','interval_paused')
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT  customer_id FROM TABLE
WHERE status = 'active'
```

Comment: I think the EXCEPT function is not supported by Impala. I tried this but I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table
where customer_id in 
(select customer_id from table 
where status in ('interval_paused','user_paused') )
```

Answer (score 0):

To exclude any customer with 'active' in either column use the following:

```
select * from customers 
where paused_statuses != 'active'
and status != 'active';
```

Comment: please add some more explanation to your answer: what have you changed, where are the differences to the ops origianl code, why did you do changes, etc. this helps others to understand why you answer is really a answer and why it works now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all customers with a status of 'active' quite easily:

```
SELECT customerid FROM table WHERE status = 'active'
```

If you want to exclude any customer from your results if they have an active row, you can do this in a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE /* your other query restrictions */
AND customerID NOT IN
(
    SELECT customerid FROM table WHERE status = 'active'
)
```

This will let you eliminate any row with a customerid that has any 'active' row.

Please note that subqueries are not always the most efficient solution - there could be cases where a subquery would make your query very slow.

Comment: Thanks! I think that for this case this would work quite well. The thing, though, is that I'm already using two subqueries to get the result as you see in the image. The table is way more complex than that.

Comment: @Kreiven - There's plenty of other ways to exclude rows.  You can also try selecting your results into a temp table, and removing any customerids from the temp table if they have an active row.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need distinct or not, but here are 2 approaches. I think both will work in Impala but just in case you have an option. The first uses a "left excluding join" (make the join then exclude the matched rows) which enable us to ignore the active status customers. The second uses an even more traditional "not exists" approach to remove customer_ids that have an active status.

```
select /* distinct */ t1.customer_id 
from table t1
left join table t2 on  t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id and t2.status = 'active'
where t2.customer_id IS NULL
and t1.status in ('interval_paused','user_paused')
;

select /* distinct */ t1.customer_id 
from table t1
where t1.status in ('interval_paused','user_paused')
and NOT EXISTS (
     select null
     from table t2
     where t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
     and t2.status = 'active'
     )
;
```

if your existing query is complex, then to simplify these additions, use a [**WITH clause**](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/impala_with.html#with) like this:

```
WITH MyCTE AS (

    -- place the whole existing query here

)
select /* distinct */ t1.customer_id 
from MyCTE t1
left join MyCTE t2 on  t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id and t2.status = 'active'
where t2.customer_id IS NULL
and t1.status in ('interval_paused','user_paused')
;
```

Notice that that the name you give it ("MyCTE") can be reused in the subsequent query - a very useful feature indeed.

In general the structures created by `WITH` are called `common table expressions` (CTE) if you are wondering why I use "MyCTE" as a name.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT customer_id, paused_statuses, status
 FROM Customer
 WHERE NOT IN (SELECT customer_id, paused_statuses, status
               FROM Customer
               WHERE status = user_paused 
                  AND status = active 
                  AND status = interval_paused) 
  GROUP BY customer_id

  OR

 SELECT customer_id, paused_statuses, status
 FROM Customer
 WHERE status = user_paused 
     AND status = interval_paused
     AND status <> active
 GROUP BY customer_id
```